# Compare 2 data tables with a condition

Tags: c#, loops, datatable

I have a `DataTable` `dtA`, with the below records:

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
1001     ARCH
1001     ARCH
1002     CUSS
1003     ARCH
```

And another `DataTable` `dtB` with records as below:

```
ColumnA
ARCH
CUSS
```

I need to compare both the `DataTables` as such, if there is `ARCH` in `dtB`, search for `ARCH` in `dtA`, when the first occurrence of `ARCH` is found in `dtA`, stop the search further and write to a Log.

If `ARCH` is not present in `dtA`, then take the 2nd record of `dtB`, which is `CUSS`, when the first occurrence of `CUSS` is encountered in `dtA`, stop the search further and write to the Log.

I tried it using `DataTable.Select()` method but wasn't able to successfully do it.

Experts please help.

EDIT:

```
bool flag = true; 
for (int counter = 0; counter < dtB.Rows.Count; counter++) 
{ 
var contains = dtA.Select("ColumnB = '" + dtB.Rows[counter][0].ToString() + "'"); 
if (contains.Length == 0 && flag == true) 
{ 
dtLogs.Rows.Add("CostCode not present in the Excel");
 flag = false; 
break; 
} 
}
```

Regards

Comment: Please show the line with Select() from your code

Comment: bool flag = true;
for (int counter = 0; counter < dtB.Rows.Count; counter++)
{
var contains = dtA.Select("ColumnB = '" + dtB.Rows[counter][0].ToString() + "'");
if (contains.Length == 0 && flag == true)
{
dtLogs.Rows.Add("CostCode not present in the Excel");
flag = false;
break;
}
}

Comment: Please add the code **formatted** to your question. Its not readable here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet` as efficient lookup collection which i'd use if you need it more than once:

```
var lookup = new HashSet<string>(dtA.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnB")));
foreach(DataRow row in dtB.Rows)
{
    string value = row.Field<string>("ColumnA");
    if(lookup.Contains(value))
    {
        // write to log
    }
}
```

You could also use `Enumerable.Contains` which needs less memory but more CPU cycles:

```
var allBinA = dtA.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnB"));
foreach (DataRow row in dtB.Rows)
{
    string value = row.Field<string>("ColumnA");
    if (allBinA.Contains(value))
    {
        // write to log
    }
}
```

Comment: hi..Thanks for reply..Let me try

Comment: Hi Tim...I have used your second piece of code. It works pretty well. Can you explain me what exactly does it do?

Comment: @Anurag: it just uses `Enumerable.Contains` to find a value in an `IEnumerable<string>`. It is similar to a `foreach` loop that stops(breaks) as soon as a value is found. But it looks nicer ;)

Comment: Thank you for the code and the explanation. Appreciate it.